# API Gateway domain name returns 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-route53

I use [sst.dev](https://sst.dev) to deploy my API to AWS, I have added a [custom external domain](https://docs.sst.dev/constructs/Api#using-externally-hosted-domain) to my app through SST code (I set a specific sub domain for the API), and in AWS's dashboard -> API gateway -> "Custom domain names" I can see the sub domain I set in SST and I see that I have an amazonaws.com URL over there under "API Gateway domain name", when I try to browse to that AWS URL (to any of the endpoints of my API) all I get is status code `404` with body `{"message":"Not Found"}`, I even tried to point my custom sub domain (the one I set in SST) via CNAME to that URL just in case that's the only way the URL would respond, but when I point my domain to it I don't even get a response at all, just browser's error "This site can’t be reached".

Few notes:

- My domain is not in route53, and its DNS isn't forwarded to route53 (due to some business rules and limitations I can't do that), but I did successfully issue a certificate using ACM
- I have multiple API gateway APIs pointing to that single sub domain - In SST I set [multiple API constructs](https://docs.sst.dev/constructs/Api#mapping-multiple-apis-to-the-same-domain) to the same sub domain, that's why I don't want to use the invoke URL of each of the APIs
- My plan is to make the above AWS URL work (instead of responding with 404 for every endpoint and method), then put it behind a CloudFront distribution with some WAF rules, and I already tried to put it behind a CloudFront distribution but it still didn't work

I'd appreciate any help with this issue :)